# Configuring screen orientation on Android

Tags: android, cordova, orientation

I am developing an Android app with Cordova, I use this line in AndroidManifest.xml in order to force a landscape:

```
android:screenOrientation="landscape"
```

And it works, but the problem when you flip your phone over 180* the landscape will stay reverse, like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Make it `android:screenOrientation="sensorLandscape"` instead.